# Formatting tool for sublime text

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I am looking for a formatting/indetation tool for sublime text 2, which on `ctrl+s` turns the following code

```
if(a==2){b=a+2;}
```

to something like

```
if(a == 2) {
   b = a + 2;
}
```

I can't find anything useful. Please help.

Answer (score -10, accepted):

I have worked around an easy solution for my code indentation/formatting problem. I am using an online formatting tool [JSBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/). I just copy my whole code and paste it in jsbeautifier and after it formats my code I copy my formatted code and paste it back to my js file.

Comment: Why did you select your own answer when there were others that answered correctly? @Ali Mamedov's answer should be selected

Comment: This is not a good solution, as you do not know if bad actors could steal your pasted JSON for corporate espionage or other nefarious purposes

Answer (score 7):

You can use [JsFormat](https://github.com/jdc0589/JsFormat)

> JsFormat is a JavaScript formatting plugin. Behind the scenes, it uses
>   the command line formatter from [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org) to format full or
>   portions of JavaScript and JSON files.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Beautify](https://github.com/enginespot/js-beautify-sublime) or [HTML/CSS/JS beautify](https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify)

Comment: Can we install it on unsubscribed version and how do I install it?

Comment: @NitinAggarwal: Yes, you can install any packages on the unregistered version of SublimeText. See **PackageControl** [**Installation**](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) and [**Usage**](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/usage).

Comment: yeah, use package control. This is the best thing in the sublime text world.

Answer (score 2):

[**CoolFormat**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CoolFormat) offers various
[**bracket, indentation, whitespace, & formatting styles**](http://akof1314.github.io/CoolFormat/doc/Cpp.html) for the following langauges:

- `C`, `C++`, `C#`, `CSS`, `HTML`, `Java`, `JavaScript`, `JSON`, `Objective-C`, `PHP`, `SQL`, `XML`